# Where can I find recent tables with the average cumulative default rates?

Tags: default-probability, credit-ratings, default-risk

I'm mostly interested in Moody's average corporate cumulative default rates, possibly in 2020 or the latest version. I tried to take a look at Moody's website but I am still in trouble. The latest version I've found is from 15 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem, because the available annual default studies did not have these information (to the best of my knowledge). Cumulative default rates can be found in the series *Semi-Annual Performance Statistics*, which is a short publication with the average historical corporate default rates and structured finance impairment rates for various time horizons. There is a breakdown by letter rating and geographical region. The latest version that I managed to find is the following:

**Moody’s Investors Service (2018) Cross-sector: Semi-annual performance statistics update:
2018 H1**

This report includes cumulative default rates for the periods 1983-2018, 2008-2018 and 2013-2018.